# How to add a composite primary key to an already created table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I have looked at other questions but their solutions have not worked for me. I have a table with 2 columns, and when attempting to run

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD PRIMARY KEY (col1,col2);
```

it gives the following error:
ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "tableName" are not allowed

All solutions I have found on SO so far have given me the same issue. Is this a result of a newer version of psql?

Comment: The error message says that is not allowed to have multiple primary keys. It does says that a composite key is not allowed.

Check your table. You should have a primary key already created.

Comment: What Pedro said.  There is not enough information here to say for sure, but I can only assume that you have a primary key on tableName for either col1 or col2, and want to change it to be composite between both col1 and col2.  If that is the case, have you not tried just removing the first key before adding the new one?  That should be all you need to get it to work.

Comment: there is no primary key on the table at all. It is just a 2 column table and throws this error when i try

Comment: Try using `\d+ tableName` to check constraints placed on the table.  I'm sure there's a key already on it that you aren't aware of.

Comment: Can you add the output of my above command (`\d+ tableName`) to your question?  There may not be much more advice we can offer without the additional information.

Comment: @user3491700 - There *is* another primary key on that table - that's what the error message says.